# Looking for a fine U.S. Latitude and Longitude grid (0.25, 0.5 degree)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, latitude-longitude, vector-grid

There is a global latitude and longitude grid data available at 1 degree resolution and higher (http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f11bcdc5d484400fa926dcce68de3df7). Is anyone aware of a finer resolution dataset (at 0.25 and 0.5 degree)? Or alternatively a way to make it in ArcGIS/GDAL/Python using the 1 degree product?

Comment: Can the Fishet Tool not accomplish this?  I don't have an ArcInfo license here, but give a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Dan Patterson says [**Create Fishnet**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) is the ArcGIS way to go - and, at least at 10.1, it seems to be available at all license levels.

Comment: There is a good "demo" of how to do this on the Esri "GeoNet" forum. 
[How do I create a fishnet grid that aligns with a 15 minute data frame grid?](https://community.esri.com/thread/207696-how-do-i-create-a-fishnet-grid-that-aligns-with-a-15-minute-data-frame-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives is to us XTools or ETGeoWizards. Both have a tool for making polygon and line grids at a user specified distance (ie: 0.25 or 0.5 degrees).

Answer (score 0):

You can create 1 degree or 30 minute grids in the ArcGIS Data Frame Properties, as follows:

1. Right click your Data Frame in the TOC > Properties > Grids
2. Select *New Grid*
3. In the second window of the Grid and Graticule wizard, choose *1
   degree* for both the parallel and meridian sections.  Alternatively, choose 30
   minutes (i.e. for 0.5 degree).

You can also convert your grid to graphics within the Dataframe Properties > Grids window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "[USGS Map Indices Downloadable Data Collection](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/usgs-map-indices-downloadable-data-collection0f236)" hosts a wide variety of resolutions of lat/long grids.  As stated on their data download page:

> This data consists of data grids for the entire United States area,
>   including 1 X 2 Degree, 1 X 1 Degree, 30 X 60 Minute, 15 X 15 Minute,
>   7.5 X 7.5 Minute, and 3.75 X 3.75 Minute. The grid was generated using ESRI ArcInfo GIS software.

The USGS offers downloads in a variety of formats, but the most ubiquitous is the [ESRI Shapefile](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/MapIndices/Shape/) (grouped by state).

You can also view these datasets through an USGS hosted [ArcGIS REST Web Service](https://carto.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/map_indices/MapServer).