# How to convert a QGIS Composer Grid to polygons

Tags: qgis, print-composer, vector-grid, grids-graticules

I really like the cartographic aesthetics of the QGIS 3.10 Composer Grid, especially the border created by using the "Zebra" style and "Fit Segment Length" option.
[image: QGIS Composer Grid]

Because of its design, I'd like to use this Composer Grid as the underlying groundwork to generate a points of interest locator table.

Is it possible to **export the Composer Grid to a polygon layer** so that I can run a point-on-polygon spatial overlay?

Comment: No, you can't export it, but you can use `Create grid` tool: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-grid

Comment: @Mr.Che, thanks, I actually started by generating a polygon grid with the Create Grid tool, so I understand what you are suggesting.  However, as far as I can tell, there isn't a way to A) sync up the polygon grid with the Composer Grid or 2) create the same cartographic effect with the polygon layer as the Composer Grid.

Answer (score 1):

Since I suspected that I wouldn't be able to convert the Composer Grid to polygons, I had to start thinking outside the box.  Composer Grids are really flexible and able to match up with a variety of known grids (like Lat/Long).  They even allow you to create grids at intermediate distances/map units.

So instead of creating my own "custom" locator grid and trying to get it to match up with the Composer Grid, I decided to change my locator Grid to something I could mimic in Composer.  The answer... 7.5 minute latitude/longitude grids that I found and downloaded from the USGS (details added as answer to question "[Looking for a fine U.S. Latitude and Longitude grid (0.25, 0.5 degree)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41044/looking-for-a-fine-u-s-latitude-and-longitude-grid-0-25-0-5-degree)".

I used the polygon layer to overlay against my points of interest, and let composer work its magic and build a grid using the WGS84 with 0.125 degree units.  Ends up being a perfect match, and way easier to manage over time.